# Search command history in Console2 that mimics CTRL+R from cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin, console2

I am trying to use Cygwin inside of Console2 (for the tabs). However, I use CTRL+R to search my command history in a fuzzyish way, **a lot**.  In Console2, CTRL+R is a hot key for renaming the tab.  I can't seem to find a way to change this behavior.

I did find this on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472380/1108292.  Using the .inputrc bit is *ok*, but it only searches for the beginning of the command.  Often times I'm searching for the known file name.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to re-assign the "Rename tab" hot key, to whatever you'd like.  Once it is reassigned, CTRL+R will revert to the reverse case insensitive search.

To reassign hot keys, go to Edit > Settings > Hotkeys